# Create windows service that takes start parameters

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, console-application, topshelf

I have created a windows service using `TOPSHELF` dlls but I want to make it be able to receive parameters after installing it.

Say my `folderpath` is the place from where the service will read the file.

Here is my Start method.

```
public void Start()
        {
            _log.Info("SampleService is Started");

            _timer.AutoReset = true;
            _timer.Enabled = true;
            _timer.Start();

            //String folderpath I want to use this as a start parameter.
            GetAndConvertFileIntoXML(folderPath);

        }
```

Comment: Should i use String folderpath=Console.ReadLine(); here? will it work?

Comment: Well as a service has no console, that wont work - your program receives arguments.. If you need to pass them to the service - then look in your program.cs and either make it so your service creation has parameters, or call a method, or whatever you need...

Comment: You can no longer use the standard ways to start the service.  It cannot start automatically, you can't use the Windows service manager or the NET command.  You'll have to write another program with, say, a GUI to get the argument values and use the ServiceController.Start(string[]) overload.  This is very rarely done, it is not practical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you manually install a windows service by using the command line you can provide additional arguments that should be added to your application start easily:

```
sc create MyService binPath="notepad d:\myFile.txt"
```

Unfortunately doesn't [Topshelf](https://github.com/Topshelf/Topshelf) support this. So i took the sources and added that feature on my own. I sent the needed patch to the project (not by pull request, but by mail) but they never answered me or built the feature into the code.

After applying that patch (see bottom) you get a new method `SetArguments()` which let's define you additional parameters that your service should append to the exe path that's been called at start of your service. If you like to provide this argument also to the application when you call it with the install keyword, then it gets a little bit complicated, but it works. First the code needed to forward the desired command line argument to the service installer:

```
var host = HostFactory.New(x =>
{
    x.AddCommandLineDefinition("configuration", filename =>
    {
        configFileName = CreateFullPathName(filename);
        x.SetArguments("-configuration \"" + configFileName + "\"");
    });

    ...
});
```

If you now call your program with the command line

```
MyServiceApplication install -configuration ".\Some Sub Folder\My File.txt"
```

you can see within the services.msc that under *path to executable* of your service the parameter has been added and will be filled when the service gets started.

#### Patch file

```
Index: src/Topshelf/Runtime/HostSettings.cs
===================================================================
--- src/Topshelf/Runtime/HostSettings.cs    (original)
+++ src/Topshelf/Runtime/HostSettings.cs    (add SetArguments)
@@ -38,6 +38,11 @@
         string InstanceName { get; }

         /// <summary>
+        ///   The additional arguments that should be appended when the service is installed
+        /// </summary>
+        string Arguments { get; }
+
+        /// <summary>
         ///   Returns the Windows service name, including the instance name, which is registered with the SCM Example: myservice$bob
         /// </summary>
         /// <returns> </returns>
Index: src/Topshelf/Runtime/Windows/HostServiceInstaller.cs
===================================================================
--- src/Topshelf/Runtime/Windows/HostServiceInstaller.cs    (original)
+++ src/Topshelf/Runtime/Windows/HostServiceInstaller.cs    (add SetArguments)
@@ -114,6 +114,9 @@
             if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(settings.Name))
                 arguments += string.Format(" -servicename \"{0}\"", settings.Name);

+            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(settings.Arguments))
+                arguments += " " + settings.Arguments;
+
             return new HostInstaller(settings, arguments, installers);
         }

Index: src/Topshelf/Runtime/Windows/WindowsHostSettings.cs
===================================================================
--- src/Topshelf/Runtime/Windows/WindowsHostSettings.cs (original)
+++ src/Topshelf/Runtime/Windows/WindowsHostSettings.cs (add SetArguments)
@@ -1,14 +1,14 @@
 // Copyright 2007-2012 Chris Patterson, Dru Sellers, Travis Smith, et. al.
-//  
-// Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use 
-// this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of the 
-// License at 
-// 
-//     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 
-// 
-// Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed 
-// under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR 
-// CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the 
+//
+// Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use
+// this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of the
+// License at
+//
+//     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
+//
+// Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed
+// under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR
+// CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the
 // specific language governing permissions and limitations under the License.
 namespace Topshelf.Runtime.Windows
 {
@@ -19,8 +19,8 @@
         HostSettings
     {
         public const string InstanceSeparator = "$";
-        string _description;
-        string _displayName;
+        private string _description;
+        private string _displayName;

         /// <summary>
         ///   Creates a new WindowsServiceDescription using empty strings for the properties. The class is required to have names by the consumers.
@@ -49,6 +49,8 @@
             _description = "";
         }

+        public string Arguments { get; set; }
+
         public string Name { get; set; }

         public string DisplayName
@@ -68,7 +70,6 @@
             set { _displayName = value; }
         }

-
         public string Description
         {
             get
@@ -80,7 +81,6 @@
             set { _description = value; }
         }

-
         public string InstanceName { get; set; }

         public string ServiceName
Index: src/Topshelf/Topshelf.csproj
===================================================================
--- src/Topshelf/Topshelf.csproj    (original)
+++ src/Topshelf/Topshelf.csproj    (add SetArguments)
@@ -112,6 +112,7 @@
     <Compile Include="Configuration\HostConfigurators\SudoConfigurator.cs" />
     <Compile Include="Configuration\HostConfigurators\UninstallHostConfiguratorAction.cs" />
     <Compile Include="Configuration\HostConfigurators\UnknownCommandLineOptionHostConfigurator.cs" />
+    <Compile Include="Configuration\Options\ArgumentsOption.cs" />
     <Compile Include="Configuration\Options\AutostartOption.cs" />
     <Compile Include="Configuration\Options\DelayedOption.cs" />
     <Compile Include="Configuration\Options\DisabledOption.cs" />
@@ -221,6 +222,9 @@
   <ItemGroup>
     <Folder Include="Properties\" />
   </ItemGroup>
+  <ItemGroup>
+    <None Include="Internals\README.md" />
+  </ItemGroup>
   <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
   <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it.
        Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
Index: src/Topshelf/Hosts/InstallHost.cs
===================================================================
--- src/Topshelf/Hosts/InstallHost.cs   (original)
+++ src/Topshelf/Hosts/InstallHost.cs   (add SetArguments)
@@ -139,6 +139,11 @@
                 _dependencies = dependencies;
             }

+            public string Arguments
+            {
+                get { return _settings.Arguments; }
+            }
+
             public string Name
             {
                 get { return _settings.Name; }
Index: src/Topshelf/Configuration/HostConfigurators/CommandLineParserOptions.cs
===================================================================
--- src/Topshelf/Configuration/HostConfigurators/CommandLineParserOptions.cs    (original)
+++ src/Topshelf/Configuration/HostConfigurators/CommandLineParserOptions.cs    (add SetArguments)
@@ -61,7 +61,9 @@
                 .Or(from disp in x.Definition("displayname")
                     select (Option)new DisplayNameOption(disp.Value))
                 .Or(from instance in x.Definition("instance")
-                    select (Option)new InstanceOption(instance.Value)));
+                    select (Option)new InstanceOption(instance.Value))
+                .Or(from instance in x.Definition("arguments")
+                    select (Option)new ArgumentsOption(instance.Value)));
         }

         internal static void AddUnknownOptions(ICommandLineElementParser<Option> x)
Index: src/Topshelf/Configuration/HostConfigurators/HostConfiguratorImpl.cs
===================================================================
--- src/Topshelf/Configuration/HostConfigurators/HostConfiguratorImpl.cs    (original)
+++ src/Topshelf/Configuration/HostConfigurators/HostConfiguratorImpl.cs    (add SetArguments)
@@ -64,7 +64,7 @@
                 yield return this.Failure("Name", "must be specified and not empty");
             else
             {
-                var disallowed = new[] {' ', '\t', '\r', '\n', '\\', '/'};
+                var disallowed = new[] { ' ', '\t', '\r', '\n', '\\', '/' };
                 if (_settings.Name.IndexOfAny(disallowed) >= 0)
                     yield return this.Failure("Name", "must not contain whitespace, '/', or '\\' characters");
             }
@@ -86,6 +86,11 @@
             yield return this.Success("ServiceName", _settings.ServiceName);
         }

+        public void SetArguments(string arguments)
+        {
+            _settings.Arguments = arguments;
+        }
+
         public void SetDisplayName(string name)
         {
             _settings.DisplayName = name;
Index: src/Topshelf/Configuration/HostConfigurators/HostConfigurator.cs
===================================================================
--- src/Topshelf/Configuration/HostConfigurators/HostConfigurator.cs    (original)
+++ src/Topshelf/Configuration/HostConfigurators/HostConfigurator.cs    (add SetArguments)
@@ -17,6 +17,12 @@
     public interface HostConfigurator
     {
         /// <summary>
+        ///   Specifies additional command line arguments that should be added when the service is registered
+        /// </summary>
+        /// <param name="name"> </param>
+        void SetArguments(string arguments);
+
+        /// <summary>
         ///   Specifies the name of the service as it should be displayed in the service control manager
         /// </summary>
         /// <param name="name"> </param>
Index: src/Topshelf/Configuration/Options/ArgumentsOption.cs
===================================================================
--- src/Topshelf/Configuration/Options/ArgumentsOption.cs   (nonexistent)
+++ src/Topshelf/Configuration/Options/ArgumentsOption.cs   (add SetArguments)
@@ -0,0 +1,31 @@
+ï»¿// Copyright 2007-2012 Chris Patterson, Dru Sellers, Travis Smith, et. al.
+//  
+// Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use 
+// this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of the 
+// License at 
+// 
+//     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 
+// 
+// Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed 
+// under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR 
+// CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the 
+// specific language governing permissions and limitations under the License.
+namespace Topshelf.Options
+{
+    using HostConfigurators;
+
+    public class ArgumentsOption : Option
+    {
+        string _arguments;
+
+        public ArgumentsOption(string arguments)
+        {
+            _arguments = arguments;
+        }
+
+        public void ApplyTo(HostConfigurator configurator)
+        {
+            configurator.SetArguments(_arguments);
+        }
+    }
+}
\ No newline at end of file
Index: src/Topshelf/HelpText.txt
===================================================================
--- src/Topshelf/HelpText.txt   (original)
+++ src/Topshelf/HelpText.txt   (add SetArguments)
@@ -28,8 +28,10 @@
                         installing
       -description      The service description the service should use when
                         installing
-      -displayname      The display name the the service should use when
+      -displayname      The display name the service should use when
                         installing
+      -arguments        The command line arguments the service should
+                        also get when installing

     start               Starts the service if it is not already running

@@ -57,3 +59,10 @@
         Installs the service, appending the instance name to the service name
         so that the service can be installed multiple times. You may need to
         tweak the log4net.config to make this play nicely with the log files.
+
+    service install -arguments "-configFile \"C:\my folder\service.config\""
+        Installs the service, appending the command line argument to the
+        service so that the service will always retrieve this information
+        when started.
+        If double quotes are needed within the arguments they must be
+        escaped by a backslash \" (see example).
```

Comment: Thanks Oliver! i want to know how to pass start parameters to a service in topshelf.

Answer (score 2):

[Oliver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1838048/oliver) has a [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37417391/396746) if you wanted to go down that path. It's not something I expect to see in Topshelf (even if the patch shows up in the mail).

We don't have a way to do this in Topshelf because it's complicated to understand the context you use. We believe you should use app.config to manage this instead of command line parameters.

Let me explain the experience problem I haven't figured out: `service install --myparam=one` - Great! We modify the `IMAGE_PATH` like Oliver's patch does. Now, what should it be if you install an update with just `service install`? Should we try and keep that parameter? What if it's tied to the instance name and you just forgot it? In addition, there's no visibility into what arguments are set for a given service.

If someone helps me come up with a way to make this experience clear to users, I'd be apt to ship it with Topshelf. In the mean time, our guidance is use app.config.

Answer (score 0):

You have really easy options

```
static void Main(String[] args)
{
   ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
   ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] { new Service1(args) };
   ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
}
```

then

```
public Service1(String[] args)
{
  if (args.Length==0) // terminate with appropriate error
  else
      folderPath = arg[0]; // as an example
}
```

then in your service setup you can/must include a path.
Or, simply read it from a settings file that will be where the exe is - which is another and normal way of doing this.